# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know why this question is closed, anything wrong?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83560/pardes-end-why-could-tietjens-say-i-know

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough context for that to stand on its own as a meaningful question.

Who are Tietjens and Sylvia?  What's "Parde's End?" Is it a play or a television show?  A mystery or a comedy? A chat room? What's the setting?  Is this a dialog? If so, how are the people talking?  On the telephone?

Your question seems much harder to follow than the two-line dialog.

If you really want an answer to your question, I suggest reformatting the question, asking it anew.  This time, give sufficient context, so that everyone reading the question can understand what you're asking about, without having to locate the subtitles and scroll through the scene.

Comment: What he said. Remember, when you ask a question, you're asking for help. People who answer are, in a sense, doing you a favor. So you're much more likely to get an answer if you do as much of the work as possible. If we have to go look at a video or something, we're likely to just skip your question entirely, because (a) that's too much work, and (b) we don't know how trustworthy your link is.